# Customizing a new input that is added using a button

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, textbox

I have this piece of code below which allows me to click a button and add a new input/text box.

I was wondering if it is possible to set css for this input so it adds a textbox which is formatted the same as the existing ones?

```
 $(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         $(".addtextbox").before("<input><br>");
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the input and then give it your style in the stylesheet:

JQUERY

```
 $(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         $(".addtextbox").before("<input class='myTextBox'><br>");
     });
 });
```

CSS

```
.myTextBox{
    color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         $(".addtextbox").before("<input><br>");

         /*Your styles*/
         $(".addtextbox").style.color = "blue";
         $(".addtextbox").style.backgroundColor ='#FFFFFF';
         $(".addtextbox").style.width=200px;
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cláudio Barreira answer is great but if you want to do this in JS

**use this code to add stylesheet**

**HTML**

```
<button class="addtextbox">Add text input</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".addtextbox").click(function() {
    $(this).before("<input><br>");
    $(this).prevAll("input:first").css("background-color","red");
});
```

here you can see example
JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/00fo9pq6/